# "the Wonder Wheel, a Ferris wheel that looked " VS "the Wonder Wheel, a Ferris wheel, that looked"

Tags: grammar, appositives

> Above all, we boarded the Wonder Wheel, a Ferris wheel that looked as tall as a seven-story building. (From an ACT test)

I know "a Ferris wheel that looked as tall as a seven-story building" is used as an appositive for Wonder Wheel, but why can't it be "we boarded the Wonder Wheel, a Ferris wheel, that looked as tall as a seven-story building" where "a Ferris wheel" is still a appositive and a relative clause modifying "Wonder Wheel"？

Comment: 'Wonder Wheel' is the name of the specific ride, but 'Ferris wheel' is a generic term. So it is a Ferris wheel that looks that high and the comma is unneccessary.

Comment: @WeatherVane Surrounding "a Ferris Wheel" with quotes makes it parenthetical. That would mean that the sentence without the parenthesis would read "We boarded the Wonder Wheel that looked as tall as a seven story building". Nothing wrong with that at all as far as I'm concerned. Although the apposition would disappear.

Comment: @BoldBen I meant the comma after Ferris wheel, the topic of the question. I did not say it is wrong, but unnecessary.

Comment: Either is correct punctuation-wise. But including the comma gives a parenthetical reading, as BoldBen says ... and this reading sounds distinctly less idiomatic to my ears. If I were choosing 'the correct' one in a test, with no further context,  I'd go with the one I was happier with.

Comment: @WeatherVane I agree with you in terms of the initial one, I was addressing the supplementary part of the question where the OP asked about enclosing "a Ferris Wheel" in commas. I think we're all on the same page.